# Weighted Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality in one dimesion

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation

Weighted Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality in one dimesion states:

Let $1 < p, q < \infty, 0 < t < 1, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$ -t \leq a + b \leq 0, \frac{1}{p} < a + 1, \frac{1}{q} < b + 1, \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = a + b + t + 1 $$

Then there exists $C$ (depending on $a,b,p,q,t$) such that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{|x|^{a}|f(x)||y|^{b}|g(y)|}{|x-y|^{1-t} }dxdy \leq C\left\| f\right\| _{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\left\| g\right\| _{L^q(\mathbb{R})}.$$

The proof can probably be done by applying Marcinkiewicz interpolation. This is similar to the unweighted case, but the kernel is giving me more problems here, so some help is welcome.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this exercise. (By the way, $s=t$ here.)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Congming_Li/publication/228978704_Weighted_Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev_inequalities_and_systems_of_integral_equations/links/0912f5094057086e9f000000/Weighted-Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev-inequalities-and-systems-of-integral-equations.pdf?origin=publication_detail) paper helps. (The display can be a bit bumpy.)

Comment: This inequality is theorem $B^*_2$ on page $3$ of STEIN, E. M., and GUIDO WEISS. “Fractional Integrals on n-Dimensional Euclidean Space.” Journal of Mathematics and Mechanics, vol. 7, no. 4, 1958, pp. 503–514., www.jstor.org/stable/24900519.